# Use SQL to get session duration between two events

Tags: sql, postgresql, partitioning

I've got a dataset (in postgres specifically) that I need to calculate the 'user session time' for. I'm fairly positive I need to use partitioning to answer the question, but I'm not really sure how to go about it. The `events` table as an id, a user_id, the event category, and a date. When a user signs in, we put an event in the table for that user. Each time they visit a page, there's a similar event. The table looks similar to this:

| id | user_id | category | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | Sign-In | 2023-12-20 01:07:03 |
| 2 | 100 | Page View | 2023-12-20 01:07:05 |
| 3 | 100 | Page View | 2023-12-20 01:09:17 |
| 4 | 107 | Sign-In | 2023-12-20 01:09:19 |
| 5 | 107 | Page View | 2023-12-20 01:09:21 |
| 6 | 107 | Page View | 2023-12-20 01:09:50 |
| 7 | 100 | Page View | 2023-12-20 01:11:28 |
| .. | .. | .. | .. |
| 784 | 100 | Sign-In | 2023-12-21 17:37:31 |

To calculate the session time from user 100, let's assume that event 7 is their last page view in the system for that session. We need to get the Sign-In event (id `1`), find the last event before the Sign-In (id `7`), and subtract the two times. That'd be `2023-12-20 01:11:28 - 2023-12-20 01:07:03`, or `4 minutes and 25 seconds`. I'd want to do this for each user/sign-in combination in the dataset. For completeness, it's possible that the user doesn't have any Page Views, in which case their session time is zero. The results should look something like this:

| user_id | session_start | duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2023-12-20 01:07:03 | 00:04:25 |
| 100 | 2023-12-21 17:37:31 | null (or 00:00:00) |
| 107 | 2023-12-20 01:09:19 | 00:00:31 |

My guess is that I want to partition by user, and then by the event category, but I need the row before the one selected potentially, and not the next window. In code, I'd normally just take all the events, order them by user then by duration, and start to build a new result set by just iterating through and creation a 'session' each time I have a sign-in event. I'm just curious if this could be done in SQL on the database more efficiently.

Thanks for any help or pointers!

Comment: 1) Why is there not a 'Sign-Out'?  2) Terms are important, partition in SQL  can be [Partition](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html) or an attribute of a  [Window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html). Pretty sure you talking about the latter, but you might want to make that clearer.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, indeed, a Windowing function. The combination of OVER and PARTITION generally. But, I'm not married to that particular implementation. It was just what seemed likely to work.

As for the Sign-Out, it's because it's from a web front end. You don't really Sign-Out from that so much as close your browser. So, it doesn't track that.

Comment: You're looking for a *gaps and islands* solution.

Comment: Thanks @Stu for the idea. I'll go and look around a bit at that. Been away from SQL for a while, and am trying to do some crazy stuff with big datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trade the [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) for a clunky [scalar subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-SCALAR-SUBQUERIES) if you find it more familiar or intuitive. After all, from each `Sign-In` row, you're just looking ahead for maximum date for the same user, that's before the next `Sign-In`: [demo1](https://dbfiddle.uk/9NdaetTY)

```
select user_id,
       date as session_start,
       (select max(date) from test t2 
        where t2.user_id=t1.user_id
        and t2.date>=t1.date
        and category<>'Sign-In'
        and date<=(
            select coalesce(min(t3.date),'infinity'::timestamp) 
            from test t3 where category='Sign-In'
            and t3.date>t1.date and t3.user_id=t1.user_id)
       )-date as duration
from test t1
where category='Sign-In'
order by 1,2;
```

| user_id | session_start | duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2023-12-20 01:07:03+00 | 00:04:25 |
| 100 | 2023-12-21 17:37:31+00 | *null* |
| 107 | 2023-12-20 01:09:19+00 | 00:00:31 |

Or you can stick to window functions: [demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/Cylx2i0t)

```sql
select user_id, date as session_start, duration
from ( select *,(lead(date)over w2)-date as duration
       from ( select *,('Sign-In'=category) as is_session_start
                      ,('Sign-In'<>category and
                        'Sign-In'=lead(category,1,'Sign-In')over w1
                       ) as is_session_end
              from test t1
              window w1 as (partition by user_id order by date) 
       ) AS subquery1 where is_session_start or is_session_end
       window w2 as (partition by user_id order by date) 
) AS subquery2 where is_session_start
order by 1,2;
```

Comment: This does exactly what I need, and in two different ways. The first makes a good bit of sense to me. I had not considered trying to do it that way. Started making me think of transposition as well. And then the window functions one will help me dig in a bit more so I can see which scales better. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That is `gaps and islands` task.
You can get first `session numbers` - this is partition value, you are looking for.
Bat, really, you need  it in another aspect. For your task, grouping is enough after setting session number.
See example:

```
select user_id
  ,min(date) as session_start
  ,max(date)-min(date) as duration
from(
  select *
    ,sum(case when category='Sign-In' then 1 else 0 end)
        over(partition by user_id order by date) as session_num
  from events
  ) events_with_session_num
group by user_id,session_num
order by user_id,session_num
```

query result

| user_id | session_start | duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2023-12-20 01:07:03 | 00:04:25 |
| 100 | 2023-12-21 17:37:31 | 00:00:00 |
| 107 | 2023-12-20 01:09:19 | 00:00:31 |

For clarity, internal subquery result

| id | user_id | category | date | session_num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | Sign-In | 2023-12-20 01:07:03 | 1 |
| 2 | 100 | Page View | 2023-12-20 01:07:05 | 1 |
| 3 | 100 | Page View | 2023-12-20 01:09:17 | 1 |
| 7 | 100 | Page View | 2023-12-20 01:11:28 | 1 |
| 784 | 100 | Sign-In | 2023-12-21 17:37:31 | 2 |
| 4 | 107 | Sign-In | 2023-12-20 01:09:19 | 1 |
| 5 | 107 | Page View | 2023-12-20 01:09:21 | 1 |
| 6 | 107 | Page View | 2023-12-20 01:09:50 | 1 |

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/JvBPYuM6)